# Datagridview doesn't filtering properly

Tags: c#, windows, forms, datagridview, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with the filter of my datagridview. Currently, i'm applying 3 type of filter on date into my data (loaded by xml file) :

1. Month filter => This filter enable me to show all data relevant with the curent selected month
2. 1 date filter => show all data which are associed to the current selected date
3. X dates filter => show all data which are associed to the current selected dates (31 max)

The filter is applied by seleting dates on a CalendarMonth control. The filter is actived on this method :

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime current_date = this.monthCalendar1.SelectionStart;

    if (current_date.Month != this.old_Date.Month || current_date.Year != this.old_Date.Year)
    {
        (this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "DATE LIKE '*/" + current_date.ToString("MM/yyyy") + "'";
        System.Console.WriteLine((this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter);
        this.old_Date = current_date;
        this.label_total.Text = this.calculateSum();
        this.label_filter.Text = this.label_total.Text;
        this.label_month.Text = current_date.ToString("MMMM (yyyy)");
    }
    else
    {
        if (this.monthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Equals(this.monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")))
        {
            (this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "DATE = '" + this.monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'";
            this.label_filter.Text = this.calculateSum();
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("DATE >= '" + current_date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "' AND <= '" + this.monthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'");
            (this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("DATE >= '" + this.monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "' And DATE <= '" + this.monthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'");
            this.label_filter.Text = this.calculateSum();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem come when i have X selected dates. After selecting the date I have a strange bug. In fact, when i select 12/10 to 12/12 the filter show me the result of the october & november month ! The is no data for the december month a thoses dates.

Here a GIF of the problem :
[image]

the log for the filter say :

```
DATE >= '09/12/2015' AND <= '10/12/2015'
DATE >= '09/12/2015' AND <= '11/12/2015'
DATE >= '09/12/2015' AND <= '12/12/2015'
DATE LIKE '*/01/2016'
DATE LIKE '*/12/2015'
```

As we can see in the GIF the 2 other filters work fine. But the X selected dates didn't work like it is supposed to do ..

Anyone have an idea of the problem ?

For information :

- Visual studio (community) 2015
- C#
- Windows Form
- system in French (datetime in French, so => dd/MM/yyyy )

PS: sorry if the english ins't perfect.

Thank you.

Comment: The Edit option don't seem work then I post here => I forgot the basic in a forum message : "Hi mates." .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the bug ^^.

I used DATE column in **String** format and not in **DateTime** format. I have made all changes (in XML too) to work with DateTime value, and now the filter on X dates work fine !

Here the code of the new filtering method :

```
    private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime current_date = this.monthCalendar1.SelectionStart;
        // we will identify if is the month/year who as changed or the day (to apply a filter on the data)

        // month/year check
        if (current_date.Month != this.old_Date.Month || current_date.Year != this.old_Date.Year)
        {
            // applying basic month & year filter (standard filter)
            (this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "[DATE] >= '" + current_date.ToString("01/MM/yyyy") + "' AND [DATE] <= '" 
                + DateTime.DaysInMonth(current_date.Year, current_date.Month).ToString() + current_date.ToString("/MM/yyyy") + "'";
            System.Console.WriteLine((this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter);
            this.old_Date = current_date;
            this.label_total.Text = this.calculateSum();
            this.label_filter.Text = this.label_total.Text;
            this.label_month.Text = current_date.ToString("MMMM (yyyy)");
        }
        else
        {

            if (this.monthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Equals(current_date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")))
            {
                //only one date is selected
                // the day as changed
                (this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "[DATE] = '" + current_date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'";
                System.Console.WriteLine((this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter);
                this.label_filter.Text = this.calculateSum();
            }
            else
            {
                // more than 1 date is selected
                (this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[DATE] >= '" + current_date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "' AND [DATE] <= '" + this.monthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'");
                System.Console.WriteLine((this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter);
                this.label_filter.Text = this.calculateSum();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thx for the help @Arie ;)

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you press December 21? If there's no results, then you should probably check the `Locale` of your `DataTable` and/or `DataSet`, that is the data source for your grid.

Is the result of the following code what you expected (`dd/MM/yyyy`)?

```
Console.WriteLine((this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).Locale.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

Comment: If i only press on the 21 december I have all result of the 21 december. The filter on 1 selected date work file ^^. http://files.danstools.com/file-convert/result/20151222143827.gif

I don't need to use "Locale.DateTimeFormat" because all date given by the code is at my locale time (French system).

EDIT : I have added a value to the 21 november, and when I select the 21 December the filter is still good (only december result are displayed).

Comment: @Bloops a question:which Windows 7?8?10? Just today I had a similarily strange issue with MaskedTextBox and format of date on Windows 10 only. All locales were set and it still tried to handle my dates as if I were in the US. I had to set FormatStrings on my bindings separately.

Comment: i'm currenlty running my program on a Win 7 (64 bits)